# Локальный сервер компании

Tags: unix, веб-сервер, сервер, контроллер-домена

Всем доброго вечера.Пишу как чайник ей богу. Сам web программист. В компании хочу поставить сервер на *nix системе.Не часто сталкиваюсь с *nix системами, но начал плотно с ними взаимодействовать.Скорее всего дистрибутив Debian т.к. его многие советуют по стабильности, могу пересмотреть свою точку зрения следуя Вашим предпочтениям и аргументам тому или иному дистрибутиву.О себе и лок. сетях: - работал админом давно правда около 5 лет назад - сеть из 20 машин - win server 2000 - групповые политики и activeDirectory - Хоть убейте не знаю как это все под *nix системами делать. - когда работал в мажордомо столкнулся с apitablesНужно: - поднять контроллер домена (если можно то к примеру такой lan.домен компании в нете.ru) - авторизация пользователей на компах через логин\пароль - в основном компы под win7, но скорее всего будет *nix () кстати подскажите какой на пользовательские машинки дистриб ставить лучше. хочется уйти от микрософта т.к. в компании он спросом глобального масштаба не пользуется, в основном серфинг инета и работа с сайтом - раздача инета через сей сервер (2 сетевухи) - сетевой принтер - настройка квот и разрешенных адресов сайтов - web сервер с Apache+php+postgresql+mysql ()Статический адрес если нужен провайдер даст.Комп под сие дело есть.Готов выслушать любые дельные советы, ссылки на документацию, примеры и прочую информацию. Если есть кто-то кто может консультировать по скайпу в рамках "ты мне я тебе" т.е. вы помогаете мне по *nix я Вам по web программированию ([профиль на ХэшКоде][1]).В общем нубовские вопросы, т.к. этим не занимался, знаю что убью на это не один месяц, но не к спеху так сказать и нужно а по порядку понемногу.В общем суть проблемы я описал, дополнения если нужны я допишу.Хочется уже начать.  [1]: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/4597/shrek**p.s. при совместной работе по этому вопросу в блог выложу всех тех кто помогал и опишу полностью весь процесс установки и настройки!****pps кому интересен сей вопрос может смело писать уточнения и прочее. Совместными усилиями будет охвачено очень большое число вопросов.****ppps если кому не сложно пару раз за вопрос проголосовать, а то мне никому + не поставить, а хочется всех уважить за советы.**

Comment: up, up, up...

Comment: 1. Вы хотите всё настроить самостоятельно, или согласны использовать преднастроенные решения?2. Насколько мощный ящик под сие дело? (проц, память, какие сетевухи?)

Comment: 1. Да самостоятельно. Но могу возможно сделать проброс и открыть некоторым пользователям доступ по SSH.2. Мощный.Опишу.- AMD Phenom II X6 1100- 1Тб HDD (пока что) скоро еще 1 точно будет чтобы зеркалить.- 900WATT  Блок питания- 16Гб оперативы.На этом летать все будет :)

Answer (score 5):

Отличное железо!

Попробуйте виртуализировать задачи. Во первых это на самом деле ОЧЕНЬ просто, во вторых это очень вкусно :-). Один раз попробовав уже невозможно отказаться.

В вашем случае можно использовать бесплатную версию ESXi 4.1 - там нет лицензионного ограничения на количество используемой оперативной памяти (в 5 версии есть ограничение 8Гб).Так-же есть потрясающий продукт XenServer. В бесплатной версии вообще нет особых ограничений. На Xen-e работают самые извесные "облака" Амазона.

Насчёт контроллера домена. [Связка OpenLDAP + SAMBA уже готова и настроена](http://doc.zentyal.org/en/directory.html) и что самое главное - РАБОТАЕТ. Это готовое преднастроенное решение которое не вписывается в рамки любителей самостоятельно ковыряться и настраивать, но для реальной работы, а не тестирования и учёбы, оно подходит как нельзя лучше. Так-же в составе [этого комплекта](http://doc.zentyal.org/en/) есть много других компонентов (веб-сервер, VPN, прокси), однако их не пробовал, ничего не могу сказать.

Насчёт раздачи интернета. Опять-же, как показала практика, действительно лучше иметь отдельную "коробочку" которая будет заниматься NAT-ированием и роутерством. Вот [Mikrotik](http://routerboard.com/RB450G) например. Правда если вам нужно будет настраивать квоты, блокировки и прочее, squid не помешает всё-равно.

P.S. Почитал ответы, видел что Zentyal уже проскакивал. Попробуйте его обязательно :-) (Не реклама)

Comment: Железо впоряде ;)Интересные вещи, почитал, правда не до конца осилил. 5 ответов и инфы много, читать не перечитать.ps так и не могу всем ответчикам поставить по плюсу, репы не хватка.

Answer (score 4):

Предпочитаю разделять такие вещи как шлюз и контроллер. И Вам рекомендую это сделать в целях безопасности.

На шлюзе, естественно, iptables (это интерфейс к netfilter - стандартному функционалу ядра, сейчас заменён на http://netfilter.org/projects/nftables/) + Shorewall - одна из популярных обёрток), две сетевых карты (контроллера/адаптера Ethernet), Squid (тут на Ваше усмотрение - либо прозрачный, либо с запросом логин/пароль) - вариантов настрек шлюза в нете вагон и маленькая тележка.

На счет контроллеров домена: домены под Линухом (samba, т.е. обратная разработка протокола доступа к файлам и сетевым ресурсам SMB/CIFS): бесплатные - не обеспечивают всех функций последних серверных версий Windows (Server 2012, 2016); с AD (LDAP) несколько сложнее, но есть примеры как прикрутить (Directory Service: OpenLDAP, Calculate Directory Server). Более продвинутые - либо коммерческого исполнения (PowerBroker Identity Services Open AD Bridge), либо в бэта тестах или сыроваты.

Comment: Это да. Я потом об этом подумал прикупить какое-нить старенькое или маломощное под шлюз. и поставить его рядышком.

Comment: @TLT-IX-Ilya вы добавили достаточно много информации. Вполне можно было бы и отдельный ответ написать.

Answer (score 4):

Вот как делаю я. Шлюз делаю на FreeBSD (с моей точки зрения это всё же более надежно чем любой из Linux), только без всяких GUI. На шлюзе, естественно, файерволл (я пользую pf) c NAT, тут же делается проброс портов если нужно удалённое управление узлами во внутренней сети. Внутри сети DMZ и собственно локалка. В DMZ - почтовый сервер, web-сервер (если они, конечно, нужны) и прокси. Всё вполне можно разместить на одной машине под управлением той же FreeBSD. В качестве почтвового сервера настоятельно рекомендую sendmail + qpopper (эту связку еще долго никто не переплюнет), в качестве web-сервера - apache2.x (используйте именно 2.х и не слушайте всякие бредни о её нестабильности и неправильной работе). В качестве прокси - squid. Для учета трафика и ограничения трафика пользователей - пользуем traficmeter (берём отсюда - http://freeprogrammer.ru/index.php/articles/115-squid-trafic-acc - больше нигде не найдёшь, ибо моя разработка), если просто учёт трафика нужен (без ограничения юзеров - такое тоже иногда бывает) - тогда SLA (тоже моё, если найдёшь где-то ещё - значит спёрли у меня, но мне не жалко, хотел поделиться и поделился). Авторизацию наподобие Active Directory можно сделать при помощи LDAP (всё можно поднять под FreeBSD). В локальной сети ставишь рабочие машинки (под виндой или под юнихом/линухом - дело вкуса, но если под линухом - рекомендую openSUSE, описание установки можно взять тут http://freeprogrammer.ru/index.php/articles/109-opensuse-install). Можно и более подробно, но тогда уж с вопросами - лично ко мне.

Comment: Слушай, а Генту вместо фряхи не прокатит?Просто я уже общаюсь с одним человеком, он советует Генту.Выдержка:"Вообще, личное предпочтение - Gentoo и FreeBSD.Гента на домашнем сервере, под фрёй нет виртуализации, скажемЧем-то похожа на фряху, но более гибкая и удобная"Ну вот как-то так. Я пока собираю этот сервак, корпус большой и времени много нет, так что сегодня завтра доделаю его и смогу уже впихнуть диск и начать устанавливать.

Answer (score 2):

Про контолер домена на базе линукса я так думаю забудь, можно сделать что то подобное но это будет уже совсем не то.... и думаю даж не стоит. Компы оставь на win7 так как скорее всего они работают с документами и  не все word документы изумительно отображаются в linux. можешь конечно под wine запустить word (но выглядет убого, хотя можно конечно и виртуалку сделать будет чуть получше). принтеры и фаловый ресурс это sambaинтернет и сеть squid+sams (так проще тебе будет чем ручками все заполнять)web сервер - nginx

Comment: Про контроллер домена как-то необоснованно. Мало примеров того что это неправильное решение. Писать что "думаю даж не стоит" на чем основано? Просто что это так смутно звучит или что?Увы нужен именно контроллер домена.Про OpenOffice скажу так, обработка доков на нем вполне нормально проходит.Так что это в планах все равно есть и будет. Работа в основном в браузере т.к. там все ПО написано уже. Домен есть реальный под работу.Ldap+samba на Gentoo планируется делать.Извращение типа запуск под wine не будет.Один участник уже помогает в вопросе.

Comment: Я тока рад за Вас ! ))))

Comment: Так может есть советы какие-нить? Я готов к "съеданию" информации.

Answer (score 2):

Для пользовательских компов я уже в течении 4 лет использую мандриву и к ней wine etersoftс поддержкой терминального вариант, для запуска виндовых приложений работает стабильно, могут быть некоторые проблемы с отдельными принтерами. Для серверной части использую Ubuntu server. с Поднятыми необходимыми серверами. Администрирование через WEBMIN. Посмотрите в сторону Zentyalzentyal.orgвсе на базе ubuntu с гуем, там вам и контроллер домена и файловый сервер, и DNS вместе с DHCP.Вот здесь есть мануалы http://www.howtoforge.com/howtos/samba

Comment: Интересно, я про Мандриву и wine etersoft. как то читал про это но про применения никто не писал. Спасибо.

Comment: Счас перевожу кантору на Мандриву 2011, и Wine-etersoft 2.0 для 1C-8,Все работает.